# Why does FolderBrowserDialog not allow the desktop as SelectedPath when RootFolder is MyComputer?

Tags: .net, winforms

This works:

```
FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
dlg.SelectedPath = "C:\\Almo\\";
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

This does not:

```
FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
dlg.SelectedPath = "C:\\Users\\Almo\\Desktop\\";
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

The first opens a fileselection dialog starting in C:\Almo, the second started at MyComputer. Is there a way to make this work? The issue is my Application's default save location is the Desktop, and I want the user to be able to select a different location, and I want the dialog to start wherever the current location is.

Comment: It looks like MyComputer is contained by Desktop. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Desktop in Win 7 doesn't actually exist at the path

c:\Users\username\Desktop

The system pretends it does at the command prompt and in windows explorer. But since it isn't there, the part of SelectedPath that requires its path to be under RootFolder disallows setting the path in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```

Comment: My path is stored as a string, and the user can select any directory in MyComputer. This would solve the special case where the user wants to save on the desktop, and would require exception checking to see if it is the desktop. Any idea why my solution above doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
dlg.SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

this gets you the path of the desktop for the user who is running the code.

Comment: See comment on Knvn's answer.