# How to programatically delete shortcut from user's desktop?

Tags: c#, icons, shortcut, delete-file

Using C#, how can I delete a shortcut from a user's desktop?

Tried this with no success:

```
string WinUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
WinUser = WinUser.Substring(WinUser.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

File.Delete("C:\\Users\\" + WinUser + "\\Desktop\\Touch Data.lnk");
```

What am I missing? Appreciate any advice on this!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
File.Delete(Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Touch Data.lnk"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue in this question I asked:

[Why does FolderBrowserDialog not allow the desktop as SelectedPath when RootFolder is MyComputer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810189/why-does-folderbrowserdialog-not-allow-the-desktop-as-selectedpath-when-rootfold)

The answer I got was this:

> Apparently, the Desktop in Win 7 doesn't actually exist at the path
>
> c:\Users\username\Desktop
>
> The system pretends it does at the command prompt and in windows
>   explorer. But since it isn't there, the part of SelectedPath that
>   requires its path to be under RootFolder disallows setting the path in
>   that way.

It's possible this is the issue. You should use the Environment.GetFolderPath function to get a handle on the real desktop. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same scenario where I had to check if the shortcut exists and then delete it. I used the following code

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
if(System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(desktopPath , "shortcut.lnk")))
{
 System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(desktopPath , "shortcut.lnk"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.File.Delete("C:/Users/Public/Desktop/Game.lnk");
```

:)) win7 standart user name public